# When should a java PreparedStatement be closed?

Tags: java, prepared-statement

In the tutorial ["Using Prepared Statements"](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) it states that they should always be closed. Suppose I have a function

```
getPrice() {
}
```

that I expect to be called multiple times per second. Should this method be opening and closing the PreparedStatement with every single method call? This seems like a lot of overhead.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all, `PreparedStatement` are never opened. It's just a prepared `Statement` that is executed. The statement is sent to the RDBMS that executes the SQL statement compiled by the `PreparedStatement`. The connection to the SQL statement should be opened during the duration of the SQL querying and closed when no other RDMS calls is needed.

You can send many `Statement`/`PreparedStatement` as you require provided that you **finally** close its `ResultSet` and `PreparedStatement` once you're completed with them and then close the RDBMS connection.

Answer (score 13):

> Should this method be opening and closing the PreparedStatement with every single method call?

If you are creating the `PreparedStatement` object within the method, then you must close it, once you are done with it. You may reuse the `PreparedStatement` object for multiple executions, but once you are done with it, you must close it.

This is because, although all Statement objects (including PreparedStatements) are supposed to be closed on invoking `Connection.close()`, it is rarely the case. In certain JDBC drivers, especially that of Oracle, the driver will be unable to close the connection if the connection has unclosed ResultSet and Statement objects. This would mean that, on these drivers:

- You should never lose a reference to a PreparedStatement object. If you do, then the connection will not be closed, until garbage collection occurs. If you are reusing PreparedStatement instances for different SQL statements, it is easy to forget this.
- You should close the PreparedStatement once you no longer need it. Only then can the Connection.close() actually tear down the physical connection.

Answer (score 0):

As the example in the tutorial shows you should close it after all your queries have been performed.

Once the statement is closed the RDMS may release all resources associated with your statement. Thus to use it further you'd have to re-prepare the very same statement.

Answer (score 0):

I think that, after every database interaction, every component like statement, resultset must be closed, except for connection, if u tend to perform more operation.

And there is no need to worry, if you are creting the prepared statement again and again, because as you will be using the same statement again and again, there wont be any performannce issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes..No issues are there if you are creating the prepared statement n number of times, because as you will be using the same statement at all the places. No need to have any observation here regarding performance

Thanks