# Using profiling tool to find the exact reason for outOfMemoryError in the java code

Tags: java, linux, jdbc

Hi i have a java program for accessing remote as well as local databases at the same time using JDBC.

But i am getting this exception:
->Exception in thread "Thread-1964" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Now i wanted to use any profiling tool through whic i can get exact reason for this exception in my code.

This is my java program

```
public class DBTestCases{

    Connection localConnection; 
    Connection remoteConnection;
    Connection localCon;
    Connection remoteCon;
    List<Connection> connectionsList;
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String user = "root";
    String password = "root";
    String dbName = "myDB";
    String connectionUrl1= "jdbc:mysql://11.232.33:3306/"+dbName+"?user="+user+"&password="+password+"&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&autoReconnect=true&failOverReadOnly=false&maxReconnects=10";
    String connectionUrl2= "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"+dbName+"?user="+user+"&password="+password+"&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&autoReconnect=true&failOverReadOnly=false&maxReconnects=10";

    public List<Connection> createConnection() {

        try {
                    Class.forName(driver);
                    localCon = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl2);
                    if(localCon != null)
                        System.out.println("connected to remote database at : "+new Date());
                    remoteCon = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl1);
                    if(remoteCon != null)
                        System.out.println("connected to local database at : "+new Date());
                    connectionsList = new ArrayList<Connection>( 2 );
                    connectionsList.add( 0 , localCon );
                    connectionsList.add( 1 , remoteCon );
                } catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
                    cnfe.printStackTrace();
                    } catch(SQLException sqle) {
                        sqle.printStackTrace();
                        }
        return connectionsList;
    }

    public void insert(){

        Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
        PreparedStatement ps1 = null;
        PreparedStatement ps2 = null;
        String sql = "insert into user1(name, address, created_date)" +
                                " values('johnsan', 'usa', '2013-08-04')";
        if(remoteConnection != null&&localConnection != null) {
            System.out.println("Database Connection Is Established");
            try {
                        ps1 = remoteConnection.prepareStatement(sql);
                        ps2 = localConnection.prepareStatement(sql);
                        int i = ps1.executeUpdate();
                        int k = ps2.executeUpdate();
                        if(i > 0) {
                            System.out.println("Data Inserted into remote database table Successfully");
                        }
                        if(k > 0) {
                            System.out.println("Data Inserted into local database table Successfully");
                        }
                    } catch (SQLException s) {
                            System.out.println("SQL code does not execute.");
                            s.printStackTrace();
                        }catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
            }
            System.out.println("Inserting values in db");
        }
        };
        Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
        thread.start();
    }

    public void retrieve(){

        Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
        try {
                    Statement st1 = localConnection.createStatement();
                    Statement st2 = remoteConnection.createStatement();
                    ResultSet res1 = st1.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM  user1");
                    ResultSet res2 = st2.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM  user1");
                    System.out.println("---------------------------Local Database------------------------");
                    while (res1.next()) {
                        Long i = res1.getLong("userId");
                        String s1 = res1.getString("name");
                        String s2 = res1.getString("address");
                        java.sql.Date d = res1.getDate("created_date");
                        System.out.println(i + "\t\t" + s1 + "\t\t" + s2 + "\t\t"+ d);
                    }
                    System.out.println("------------------------Remote Database---------------------");
                    while (res2.next()) {
                        Long i = res2.getLong("userId");
                        String s1 = res2.getString("name");
                        String s2 = res2.getString("address");
                        java.sql.Date d = res2.getDate("created_date");
                        System.out.println(i + "\t\t" + s1 + "\t\t" + s2 + "\t\t"+ d);
                    }
        } catch (SQLException s) {
                System.out.println("SQL code does not execute.");
                s.printStackTrace();
        }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
        };
        Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
        thread.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DBTestCases dbTestCases = new DBTestCases();
        List l = dbTestCases.createConnection();
        dbTestCases.localConnection = (Connection)l.get(0);
        dbTestCases.remoteConnection = (Connection)l.get(1);
        for(;;) {
            dbTestCases.insert();
            dbTestCases.countRows();
            dbTestCases.retrieve();
        }
    }
}
```

PLease can anybody help me which is the best tool to use and how i have to use it,and any links for this.i am using linux operating system.

I think i am starting a new thread for each call of method can anybody suggest how to close thread before starting it again or use thred pool..

Thankyou in advance.

Comment: How much data is in your USER1 table?

Answer (score 1):

The same problem has happened to me once. The problem is your java reserved heap memory. This heap memory is configurable through one of the java config files; both it's minimum and maximum amount.

Comment: can you please tell me how you resolved it,and i also wanted to use any profiler tool can youi sujjest any.

Comment: -Xms<size> set initial Java heap size          -Xmx<size> set maximum Java heap size        -Xss<size> set java thread stack size java -Xms16m -Xmx64m ClassName

Comment: You should put all those configs while running the application. Just like the example.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lots of profilers.
I have been using Visual VM for a while and that's useful for me, at least. It's easy to use and pretty powerful tool as well.
Here's the link:
http://visualvm.java.net

Not sure which IDE you are using. But there's nothing do do with OutOfMemoryError which mean that it's a RuntimeException.

Comment: i am not using any IDE i am writing code in bluefish editor in linux operating system

Answer (score 0):

A little bit of offtopic (because I'm not going to suggest you a profiler), but the problem, I think, comes from these lines

```
ps1 = remoteConnection.prepareStatement(sql);
ps2 = localConnection.prepareStatement(sql);
int i = ps1.executeUpdate();
int k = ps2.executeUpdate();
```

and

```
Statement st1 = localConnection.createStatement();
Statement st2 = remoteConnection.createStatement();
ResultSet res1 = st1.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM  user1");
ResultSet res2 = st2.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM  user1");
```

After you create PreparedStatement and use it, you should close it. Either you should use close() method when you don't need it anymore or use try-with-resources (it use close() automatically). [Java Tutorial on statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) and on [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). Also consider reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353046/when-should-a-java-preparedstatement-be-closed) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17788132/java-implicit-try-with-resources) topics.

A would rewrite your code something like this (didn't actually tried it, but it compiles and it supposed to eliminate problems with memory leaks):

```
public class DBTestCases {

    Connection localConnection;
    Connection remoteConnection;
    Connection localCon;
    Connection remoteCon;
    List<Connection> connectionsList;
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String user = "root";
    String password = "root";
    String dbName = "myDB";
    String connectionUrl1= "jdbc:mysql://11.232.33:3306/"+dbName+"?user="+user+"&password="+password+"&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&autoReconnect=true&failOverReadOnly=false&maxReconnects=10";
    String connectionUrl2= "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"+dbName+"?user="+user+"&password="+password+"&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&autoReconnect=true&failOverReadOnly=false&maxReconnects=10";

    public List<Connection> createConnection() {

        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
            localCon = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl2);
            if(localCon != null)
                System.out.println("connected to remote database at : "+new Date());
            remoteCon = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl1);
            if(remoteCon != null)
                System.out.println("connected to local database at : "+new Date());
            connectionsList = new ArrayList<Connection>( 2 );
            connectionsList.add( 0 , localCon );
            connectionsList.add( 1 , remoteCon );
        } catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
            cnfe.printStackTrace();
        } catch(SQLException sqle) {
            sqle.printStackTrace();
        }
        return connectionsList;
    }

    public void insert(){

        Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                PreparedStatement ps1 = null;
                PreparedStatement ps2 = null;
                String sql = "insert into user1(name, address, created_date)" +
                        " values('johnsan', 'usa', '2013-08-04')";
                if(remoteConnection != null&&localConnection != null) {
                    System.out.println("Database Connection Is Established");
                    try {
                        ps1 = remoteConnection.prepareStatement(sql);
                        ps2 = localConnection.prepareStatement(sql);
                        int i = ps1.executeUpdate();
                        int k = ps2.executeUpdate();
                        if(i > 0) {
                            System.out.println("Data Inserted into remote database table Successfully");
                        }
                        if(k > 0) {
                            System.out.println("Data Inserted into local database table Successfully");
                        }
                    } catch (SQLException s) {
                        System.out.println("SQL code does not execute.");
                        s.printStackTrace();
                    }catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        if (ps1 != null) {
                            try {
                                ps1.close();
                            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                                System.out.println("Cannot close ps1 statement.");
                            }
                        }

                        if (ps2 != null) {
                            try {
                                ps2.close();
                            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                                System.out.println("Cannot close ps2 statement.");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Inserting values in db");
            }
        };
        Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
        thread.start();
    }

    public void retrieve(){

        Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                Statement st1 = null;
                Statement st2 = null;
                ResultSet res1 = null;
                ResultSet res2 = null;
                try {
                    st1 = localConnection.createStatement();
                    st2 = remoteConnection.createStatement();
                    res1 = st1.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM  user1");
                    res2 = st2.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM  user1");
                    System.out.println("---------------------------Local Database------------------------");
                    while (res1.next()) {
                        Long i = res1.getLong("userId");
                        String s1 = res1.getString("name");
                        String s2 = res1.getString("address");
                        java.sql.Date d = res1.getDate("created_date");
                        System.out.println(i + "\t\t" + s1 + "\t\t" + s2 + "\t\t"+ d);
                    }
                    System.out.println("------------------------Remote Database---------------------");
                    while (res2.next()) {
                        Long i = res2.getLong("userId");
                        String s1 = res2.getString("name");
                        String s2 = res2.getString("address");
                        java.sql.Date d = res2.getDate("created_date");
                        System.out.println(i + "\t\t" + s1 + "\t\t" + s2 + "\t\t"+ d);
                    }
                } catch (SQLException s) {
                    System.out.println("SQL code does not execute.");
                    s.printStackTrace();
                }catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if (res1 != null) {
                        try {
                            res1.close();
                        } catch (SQLException ex) {
                            System.out.println("Cannot close res1 result set.");
                        }
                    }

                    if (st1 != null) {
                        try {
                            st1.close();
                        } catch (SQLException ex) {
                            System.out.println("Cannot close st1 statement.");
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    if (res2 != null) {
                        try {
                            res2.close();
                        } catch (SQLException ex) {
                            System.out.println("Cannot close res2 result set.");
                        }
                    }

                    if (st2 != null) {
                        try {
                            st2.close();
                        } catch (SQLException ex) {
                            System.out.println("Cannot close st2 statement.");
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
        thread.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DBTestCases dbTestCases = new DBTestCases();
        List l = dbTestCases.createConnection();
        dbTestCases.localConnection = (Connection)l.get(0);
        dbTestCases.remoteConnection = (Connection)l.get(1);
        for(;;) {
            dbTestCases.insert();
            dbTestCases.countRows();
            dbTestCases.retrieve();
        }
    }
}
```

There is also another problem with these statements:

```
ResultSet res1 = st1.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM  user1");
ResultSet res2 = st2.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM  user1");
```

I should never (with very rare exceptions) read entire table without using conditions in `WHERE`. Also if you need only one column `created_date`, then you must rewrite it like this:

```
ResultSet res1 = st1.executeQuery("SELECT created_date FROM  user1");
ResultSet res2 = st2.executeQuery("SELECT created_date FROM  user1");
```

But I didn't actually replaced it in a full listing, because it can be just 'quick and dirty' code. :)

Comment: but i tried closing connection ,as i am calling infinitly its showing cannot use after closing connection like that.

Comment: If i close in finally,its showing that exception already closed cant do any operations after closing connection..

Comment: But you create these objects (PreparedStatement, Statement and ResultSet) each time you run methods `insert()` and `retrieve()`. I do not close connections in your code, just statements and result sets, that use your connections.

Comment: Can you please tell me what will happen if we dont close these objects that you have listed and connections.

Comment: These objects are not collected by garbage collector. So, after some time, memory of a Java virtual machine will be full and you will get `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` error. This will not happen right away, it takes some time for Java Heap to fill up. But it will happen if you keep creating these objects and not closing them. As far as I can see it happens on 1964th thread creation on your PC (number may vary from time to time). I am not suggesting closing connections. In your case it is better to reuse them (I would even reuse PreparedStatements, but you must do this wisely).